# How do I match comments where the start and the end character are the same?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, comment

I have a programming language I want to make a major mode for where both the start and the end characters of a comment are the same. Specifically `#`.

```
#
This is a comment
#
```

As you can see it can match either multiple lines as well as single lines.
Single lines are no problem, that can be done with this regex in a `font-lock-defaults` block:  `"#\\([^#]*?\\)#`.

However the problem occurs on multiple line comments.
Due to the start and the end being the same Emacs sometimes misjudges which part of the code is actually a comment, especially if one part of the comment is off-screen.

```
#
This is a comment and should always be recognized
#
This isn't a comment but is sometimes recognized if the top is off screen
#
This is a comment and is always recognized but sometimes isn't if the last block is wrongly detected as a comment
#
```

I've also tried this code set as the `syntax-propertize-function`

```
(defconst amanatsu-comment-regex
 "\\(#\\([^#]*?\\)#\\)" )
(defun amanatsu-syntax-propertize-function (start end)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (while (re-search-forward amanatsu-comment-regex end 'noerror)
      (let ((a (match-beginning 1))
            (b (match-end 1))
            (comment-fence (string-to-syntax "!")))
        (put-text-property a (1+ a) 'syntax-table comment-fence)
        (put-text-property (1- b) b 'syntax-table comment-fence)))))
```

but this occasionally suffers the same off-screen errors.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

font-lock typically highlights chunks of your buffer at a time. Each line is a  couple of lines long.

You can solve this in (at least) two ways:

1. Expand the region that font-lock highlights by defining your own `font-lock-extend-region-functions`.
2. Ensure that your syntax propertize function works even if `start` and `end` happens to be in the middle of a comment block.

To visually see how font-lock refontifies a buffer, you can use the package [highlight-refontification](https://github.com/Lindydancer/highlight-refontification).

An example of a package that use `font-lock-extend-region-functions` is [highlight-doxygen](https://github.com/Lindydancer/highlight-doxygen).

Comment: I'm sorry I'm quite new to Emacs, how could I implement this?

Comment: You can bind a function to the variable `font-lock-extend-region-function`. This function is called whenever font-lock is about to highlight a few lines. It can extend these lines so that a larger area is rehighlighted. It does this by setting `font-lock-beg` and `font-lock-end`. For an example, see `highlight-doxygen-extend-region-full-comment` in the `highlight-doxygen` package I mentioned in the answer.